# How does one Read an external applications DrawText drawn text

Tags: c#, external, drawstring, drawtext

I have been struggeling a long time with this question: "How does one Read an external applications DrawText drawn text?".

Im coding in C# right now.

It is not possible for me to use Optical Character Recogniniton and i would prefer not to Hook or anything as intusive.

But can it be done and if yes, How?

Comment: Use the accessibility API (UI Automation namespace).

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I do not understand your question clearly, but here is what I make of it.

There is an application (Notepad.exe) that has some text written somewhere (Notepad's text editing area) and you would like to read it from your own application (YourOwn.exe).

You cannot do much using C#. Go for Win32 API. Following links might of interest:

1. EnumWindows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx
2. GetWindowText: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx
3. Complete API for Window Manipulation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632595(v=vs.85).aspx
4. Dot Net - Win32 - pinvoke.net: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumwindows

Comment: Ty i know about these functions, but they do not cover how to get text which is drawn by e.g. DrawString. Or am i wrong?

Comment: Ahh I see, my bad. I am out of solutions as of now :(